# angularjs достучаться до константы модуля из контроллера

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

есть такой вот модуль

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('lss-angular-country',[])
    .constant('COUNTRIES',[
{code:'AF',name:'Afghanistan'},{code:'AL',name:'Albania'},{code:'DZ',name:'Algeria'}.....
```

там дальше продолжение массива. 
Этот модуль включается в конфиг файла app.js и файл в  index.html

Это app.js

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('app', [
    'config',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngMaterial',
    'angular.filter',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.calendar',
    'lss-angular-country',
```

Вопрос: как мне к COUNTRIES из контроллера?
на подобие:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /* jshint latedef:nofunc */

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('agentsRegisterCtrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log(COUNTRIES); // <---------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны использовать dependency injection, добавив константу в параметры

```
.controller('agentsRegisterCtrl', function ($scope, COUNTRIES) {
    console.log(COUNTRIES);
```

Comment: Спасибище! я то думал нужно было инжектить по названию модуля - его пихал, так не получалось.

Comment: @IgorKalamurda, модули нужно пихать в зависимости модулей, а в сервисы контроллеры и т.д. можно подключать только такие же сервисы, котроллеры и т.д.